# Word 2013 normal template error at logon

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

Recently we've had an issue come up where as soon as a user with a configured email profile logs onto Windows an error pops up before explorer.exe or the start bar loads stating:

"Normal was being edited by another Word session.  If you save this document with the original name, you will overwrite any changes made in the other session."

This error actually plays a notification sound before the Welcome screen disappears.  The error window then prompts you to save the normal template under a different name.  Also immediately after this pops up and the start bar appears Outlook reminders pop up.  Neither Word nor Outlook are in the startup for Windows.  I've also gone into msconfig and disabled all startup items and this still occurs.  This does not occur if starting in safe mode.  There are no scheduled tasks in the Task scheduler and no Office related services starting with Windows.

I used Process Explorer to look at the normal template file and it states it's in use by the System Idle Process, which is odd.  The details on the systems we're seeing this on are below:

-Dell Latitude E6440; i5 8GB RAM

-Windows 7 Professional x64

-Office 2013 Home and Business

-AVG 2015 Business (tested enabled and disabled)

-Symantec DLO backup agent

-All important and optional updates installed

-All PCs are on a domain, users are local admins

Any thoughts or insight into this are greatly appreciated.  Also, saving the normal template under a different name does not resolve this issue as it comes back after a period of time.  Clicking Cancel closes the prompt but at times the error will come back up while using Office.

UPDATE:  We now have 3 machines exhibiting this behavior.  All with fresh installs of Office 2013. This occurs before AVG and Symantec are installed.

Comment: Use this tool to check startup programs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: I ran that and did not see anything related to Office except the 'click to run' service, which is required by Office to operate.  I tested setting that service to Manual but it still starts at startup.  Other than that it was system drivers and other applications

Comment: disabling the Click 2 Run service generates a different error that "Something went wrong" with Office on startup.  The other error does not appear as Office does not launch at all.

Comment: Do you have domain policy active on your network ? Maybe a startup script for user profile or machine profile start something about office.

Comment: No.  Even moved those machines to another OU.

Comment: Outlook uses the standard word template `NormalEmail.dotm`. If you don't have it locally, Word (Outlook) automatically uses it from the "Workgroup Template Path". Do you have such a path, and is it situated on a network folder?

Comment: We are not utilizing network folders.  This is a fresh install of Windows and a fresh default install of Office on all machines.  All template files are local on the machine.

Comment: I dont know why word should edit the normal template but the error you get could be created by word not having sufficent user rights. Please check the user rights on the folder that contains the normal template and you may change the rights to "all users" for testing prupose.

Comment: All users are local admins

Comment: Do you see a lock file such as ~$Normal.dotm or ~$NormalEmail.dotm` anywhere on the disk? If yes, delete it. If not, delete the .dotm files (will be recreated). Do you have installed any add-in or macro in Word or Outlook?

Comment: Haven't installed any add-ins or macros.  again, fresh install, nothing else other than what's listed in the description.  The laptop that we were seeing this on in this office will be back Thursday and I'll look for the ~$ files but I don't remember seeing them.  Also, again, it's saying the normal templates are in use by the System Idle Process when viewing the files at boot time with process explorer.

Comment: From the described config, I would suspect either AVG or Symantec of trying to send an email. Does this happen if you uninstall (not disable) them both?

Comment: This happens before AVG and Symantec are installed...

Comment: So better update the post to exclude this. However, *something* is getting executed which starts Outlook. This might be something pushed by the domain. Does this also happen before joining the domain?

Comment: We haven't tested before adding to the domain as it only happens on profiles that have had an Exchange account configured and we haven't tried configuring an email on a local account.  I will try that on the machine when it gets back in the office.  Strangely enough it does not happen on the domain admin account, even with an Exchange account setup.  Another tech suggested it may be some sort of attempt from M$ at an Office 365 integration that is causing it, even though we're not using 365 Windows is kicking off some process to attempt to open Outlook before Windows starts.

Comment: 365 is not mentioned in the post. You can find out more about what's going on at boot using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with boot logging (will slow down boot a lot).

Comment: Check the post.  Process expkorer was used.  365 isnt mentooned because we dont use it.  The behavior is strange and acts like a potential M$ attempt to use 365.  The error happens before explorer.exe loads.  Please see post for process explorer note

Comment: I was counseling Process **Monitor**.

Comment: In looking at the description Process Monitor would give me the same information as Process Explorer at this point, as the error is occurring as soon as the user logs in before explorer.exe.  At that point I'd be running it after the fact and getting the information on the process that is holding the file.  Since that doesn't give me a history of what opened it to begin with or the system call that initialized it I don't think it'd be much help further than Process Explorer.

Comment: Process Monitor can filter on almost any computer event, including launching of excutables.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Did the machines have a cripple-ware version of Outlook or Office installed, before you made the fresh install of Office 2013?  Could there be some latent garbage in the registry from the cripple-ware versions?

If so, try cleaning the cripple-ware out, before installing Office 2013.

Comment: To clarify 'cripple-ware', do you mean the partially pre-installed Office that comes on every Dell machine?

Comment: Yes, the "partial" Office.  It could be causing problems.  By analogy, the "Outlook Lite" installations used to cause similar headaches with Outlook.